# Why h-100 does not work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container bg-danger h-100">
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Exotic</div>
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Grooming</div>
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Health</div>
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Nutrition</div>
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Pests</div>
  <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Vaccinations</div>
</div><!-- container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is, why the `div` container is not 100 percent height?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As my knowledge, height 100% is the div has the height equal to its parent, but here there is no parent for it. If you want to make the div's height equal to your window height, I tried wrap it with a div height = 100vh. https://jsfiddle.net/goLfLykw/

```
    <div style="height: 100vh">
      <div class="container bg-danger h-100">
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Exotic</div>
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Grooming</div>
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Health</div>
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Nutrition</div>
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Pests</div>
        <div class="bg-warning border p-1">Vaccinations</div>
      </div>
      <!-- container -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to set HTML and BODY heights to 100 % so that the `div`s parent is full of viewport height, then the div should stretch there. This is easy to achieve with flexbox:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; display: flex; }
body > div { flex: 1; }
```

This should stretch the div across the entire viewport.